# Convert Nested set in php to nested array without depth parameter

Tags: php, recursion, nested-sets

Given an array:

```
$arrData = array(
 0 => array (
   'uid'   => 1,
   'name'  => 'label',
   'open'  => 0,
   'close' => 9
 ),
 1 => array (
   'uid'   => 2,
   'name'  => 'label',
   'open'  => 1,
   'close' => 2
 ),
 2 => array (
   'uid'   => 3,
   'name'  => 'label',
   'open'  => 3,
   'close' => 8
 ),
 3 => array (
   'uid'   => 4,
   'name'  => 'label',
   'open'  => 4,
   'close' => 5
 ),
 4 => array (
   'uid'   => 5,
   'name'  => 'label',
   'open'  => 6,
   'close' => 7
 )
);
```

Which represents this structure:

```
<label>     [0,9]
 <label />  [1,2]
 <label>    [3,8]
  <label /> [4,5]
  <label /> [6,7]
 </label>
</label>
```

I am trying to get to an array that results in this format:

```
$arrNesting = array(
 0=>array(
   'item'    => array('uid'=>1, 'name'=>'label', 'open'=>0, 'close'=>9),
   'children' => array(
     0=>array(
       'item'     => array('uid'=>2, 'name'=>'label', 'open'=>1, 'close'=>2),
       'children' => array()
     ),
     1=>array(
       'item'     => array('uid'=>3, 'name'=>'label', 'open'=>3, 'close'=>8),
       'children' => array(
         0=>array(
           'item'     => array('uid'=>2, 'name'=>'label', 'open'=>4, 'close'=>5),
           'children' => array()
         ),
         1=>array(
           'item'     => array('uid'=>3, 'name'=>'label', 'open'=>6, 'close'=>7),
           'children' => array()
         )
       )
     )
   )
 )
);
```

via a function call like this:

```
// $arrData: Source Data with keys for denoting the left and right node values
// 'open': the key for the left node's value
// 'close': the key for the right node's value
$arrNested = format::nestedSetToArray( $arrData, 'open', 'close' );
```

So far, I've tried this format, assuming the $arrData values **will always be in left value ascending order**. The uid values 'happen' to also be in order, but are not relied upon to be so:

```
public static function nestedSetToArray( $arrData = array(), $openKey='open', $closeKey='close') {
// Hold the current Hierarchy
$arrSets = array();

// Last parent Index, starting from 0
$intIndex = 0;

// Last Opened and Closed Node Values, and maximum node value in this set
$intLastOpened = 0;
$intLastClosed = null;
$intMaxNodeNum = null;

// loop through $arrData
foreach( $arrData as $intKey=>$arrValues) {
  if( !isset( $arrSets[ $intIndex ] )) {
      // Create a parent if one is not set - should happen the first time through
      $arrSets[ $intIndex ] = array ('item'=>$arrValues,'children'=>array());
      $intLastOpened = $arrValues[ $openKey ];
      $intLastClosed = null; // not sure how to set this for checking 2nd IF below
      $intMaxNodeNum = $arrValues[ $closeKey ];
  } else {
      // The current item in $arrData must be a sibling or child of the last one or sibling of an ancestor
      if( $arrValues[ $openKey ] == $intLastOpened + 1) {
         // This is 1 greater then an opening node, so it's a child of it
      } else if( /* condition for sibling */ ) {
         // This is 1 greater than the intLastClosed value - so it's a sibling
      } else if( /* condition for sibling of ancestor */ ) {
         // This starts with a value greater than the parent's closing value...hmm
      }
  }
}
```

}

Any pointers to take this further would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should works

```
$stack = array();
$arraySet = array();


foreach( $arrData as $intKey=>$arrValues) {
    $stackSize = count($stack); //how many opened tags?
    while($stackSize > 0 && $stack[$stackSize-1]['close'] < $arrValues['open']) {
            array_pop($stack); //close sibling and his childrens
            $stackSize--;
        }

    $link =& $arraySet;
    for($i=0;$i<$stackSize;$i++) {
        $link =& $link[$stack[$i]['index']]["children"]; //navigate to the proper children array
    }
    $tmp = array_push($link,  array ('item'=>$arrValues,'children'=>array()));
    array_push($stack, array('index' => $tmp-1, 'close' => $arrValues['close']));

}

return $arraySet;
```

I skip parametrized open and close tags but you can simply add it.

**EDIT**

What is happening here:

First the `$stack` is empty so we skip `while()`. 
Then we assign reference to `$arraySet` to the `$link`, because `$stack` is empty we push first element to `$link` which is reference to `$arraySet`. array_push()`return 1 because this is the new length of`$arraySet
`Next we add an element to the`$stack`whit values`('index' => 0, 'close' => 10)`

Next element:
Now `$stack` has 1 element, but `$stack[0]['close']` is greater than `$arrValues['open']` for element so we skip while.
Again we set reference to `$arraySet` to `$link` but now there is on element in `$stack` so we assign `$link[$stack[0]['index']]["children"]` reference to $link so now `$link` is pointing to `$arraySet[0]["children"]`. 
Now we push element to this children array. `$tmp` gives us size of this children array and we push proper element to the stack.

Next element:
It looks exactly like second one but at the beginning we pop one element from stack. So after this iteration on stack are two elements

```
('index' => 0, 'close' => 10)
('index' => 0, 'close' => 8)
```

Next element:
There is two element on stack but both have greater `close` attribute then `$arrValues['open']`  so we skip while loop. Then in navigation part:

- `$link` is pointing to `$arraySet`
- then to `$arraySet[0]["children"]`
- then to `$arraySet[0]["children"][0]["children"]`

And we push element to this array.
And so on...

Comment: I'm going to read through this a few times - I'm not sure what's happening throughout. Then I'll come back!

Comment: I delete redundant if and add some comments

Comment: I still can't follow this example :(

Comment: I add some explanations to the algorithm. My english is not very well so if you have any question please ask.

Comment: Hi :) I still don't understand how it works, but it does work and solves my problem cleanly.  If anyone could help with the wording here, this seems to be compact and efficient. Thanks!